# ActiveRecord has_many :through doesn't assign value through

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I am working with a song, genre and artist model. The classes look like below:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :song_genres
    has_many :songs, through: :song_genres
    has_many :artists, through: :songs
end
```

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :songs
    has_many :genres, through: :songs
end
```

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist
    has_many :song_genres
    has_many :genres, through: :song_genres
end
```

```
class SongGenre < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :song
    belongs_to :genre
end
```

The problem I having is when I assign a song (with a genre already assigned) to an artist, the genre isn't available to the artist instance through `artist.genres`. Below is an example of what I mean:

```
song.genres << genre
=> [#<Genre:0x00007faf02b914b0 id: 2, name: "Pop">]
[10] pry(main)> song.genres
=> [#<Genre:0x00007faf02b914b0 id: 2, name: "Pop">]
[11] pry(main)> song.artist = artist
=> #<Artist:0x00007faf044cb048 id: 2, name: "James Blunt">
[12] pry(main)> artist.genres
=> []
```

Is this how ActiveRecord works? How can I get around this?

Comment: What is `genre` in `song.genres << genre`?

Comment: Sorry, `#<Genre:0x00007faf02b914b0 id: 2, name: "Pop">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, i got the problem here. You need to `save` your `song` record before calling `artist.genres`. Genres will not be assigned to the related artist unless you save it.

```
> artist = Artist.new
 => #<Artist id: nil>

> artist.save
 => true 

> song = Song.new
 => #<Song id: nil, artist_id: nil>
> song.artist = artist
 => #<Artist id: 1>

> genre = Genre.new
 => #<Genre id: nil> 

> song.genres << genre
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Genre id: nil>]> 

# Before saving `song`
> artist.genres
  => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []> 

> song.save
 => true 

# After saving `song`
> artist.genres
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Genre id: 1>]>
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The issue with this is that I can't do `artist.genres << genre` because I get the error `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: Cannot modify association 'Artist#genres' because it goes through more than one other association.` which happens because my `Artist` class `has_many :genres, through: :songs`.

Comment: I didn't do it. You don't have to do it too.

Comment: You can do `song.genres << genre` and `song.artist = artist` instead

Comment: `artist.genres` is still empty :(

Comment: What is the exact set of statements you are running? From the beginning.

Comment: **1.** `> artist = Artist.new(name: "Bliss n Eso")
=> #<Artist:0x00007f93e0c5a7f8 id: nil, name: "Bliss n Eso">`
**2.** `> song = Song.new(name: "Eye of the Storm")
=> #<Song:0x00007f93e11e8940 id: nil, name: "Eye of the Storm", artist_id: nil>`
**3.** `> song.artist = artist
=> #<Artist:0x00007f93e0c5a7f8 id: nil,name: "Bliss n Eso">`
**4.** `> genre = Genre.new(name: "Hip Hop")
=> #<Genre:0x00007f93e0a794c0 id: nil,name: "Hip Hop">`
**5.** `> song.genres << genre
=> [#<Genre:0x00007f93e0a794c0 id: nil,name: "Hip Hop">]`
**6.** `> song.save
=> true`
**7.** `> artist.genres
=> []`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159686/discussion-between-jagdeep-singh-and-matt-hough).